# .efi can't boot when Secure Boot is enabled! do I need to get it signed?

Tags: grub2, uefi

I was told that the reasone why  the .efi (of grub 2 complided by myself) files can't boot Windows 8 which has enabled secure boot was that it hasn't been signed by some code digning certificate, such as EV Code Signing Certificate. Does that certificate work out? is there any other possible solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try [disabling Secure Boot.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) That will enable non-signed binaries to boot.

Another option is to [sign your boot loader yourself](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#using_signed) and add its key to the Machine Owner Key (MOK) list with MokManager.